# no matching function for call to 'QDomDocument::createElement(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'

Tags: c++, qt, qtxml, qdomdocument

I'm currently trying to put the values of some QLineEdits into a XML document. I use QDom for this. Here's my code:

```
void MainWindow::writeSysConf(const QString &arg1){
QFileDialog fdExport;

QString filename = fdExport.getSaveFileName(
        this,
        tr("SysConf-Konfig speichern"),
            arg1,
        tr("Konfigurationsdatei (*.xml)") );

if( !filename.isNull()) {
    QFile::remove(filename);
    if ( !filename.endsWith(".xml", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
        filename += ".xml";
    QFile file(filename);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream outPut(&file);
    QDomDocument xmlDocument;

    QDomElement sysConfigElement = xmlDocument.createElement("SYSTEMCONFIGURATION");
    QDomElement calibElement = xmlDocument.createElement("CALIB");
    QDomElement crescendoElement = xmlDocument.createElement("CRESCENDO");
    QDomElement swellsElement = xmlDocument.createElement("SWELLS");
    sysConfigElement.appendChild(calibElement);
    calibElement.appendChild(crescendoElement);

    QDomNode minNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_2->text);
    QDomNode maxNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_3->text);
    QDomNode stepsNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_4->text);
    QDomNode updateMsNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_5->text);

    crescendoElement.appendChild(minNode);
    crescendoElement.appendChild(maxNode);
    crescendoElement.appendChild(stepsNode);
    crescendoElement.appendChild(updateMsNode);

    calibElement.appendChild(swellsElement);

    xmlDocument.appendChild(sysConfigElement);
    outPut << xmlDocument.toString(4);
}
```

}

But, at these four lines:

```
QDomNode minNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_2->text);
QDomNode maxNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_3->text);
QDomNode stepsNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_4->text);
QDomNode updateMsNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_5->text);
```

it says that I would try to use an unresolved, overloaded function type to put this in my QDomNodes. But, as far as I know, QLineEdits return a QString. So where's the problem?

Comment: Do you properly link against QtXml* library?

Comment: Solved it already, will write my solution in a few seconds. It's something very obvious actually.

Comment: did you miss the `()`?

Comment: Exactly. text should be text()

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. You just need to add a () behind ui->lineEdit->text as it's a function. So mine would look like this in the proper way:

```
QDomNode minNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_2->text());
QDomNode maxNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_3->text());
QDomNode stepsNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_4->text());
QDomNode updateMsNode = xmlDocument.createElement(ui->lineEdit_5->text());
```